# 32 bit ODBC error code 193

Tags: windows, oracle, odbc

I am getting system error 193 while creating system DSN using ODBC 32 bit on x64 machine. I am using

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe file.
```

I have 64 bit Oracle 12 client installed on the same machine.
Please let me know how to fix this error.

Comment: 64-bit client means 64-bit drivers means that only a 64-bit DSN connection is possible.  Install the 32-bit client.

Comment: In case you need both, 32 bit and 64 bit Oracle Client follow this instruction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to configure a 64-bit ODBC data source (System DSN) using the #MongoDB Atlas SQL ODBC driver. https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/odbc-driver

The error I got was:

---

### Microsoft ODBC Administrator

### The setup routines for the MongoDB Atlas SQL ODBC Driver ODBC driver could not be loaded due to system error code 139 or 126: The specified module could not be found. (C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Atlas SQL ODBC Driver\bin\atsqls.dll).

I solved the problem by installing the
**Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable latest supported download**
from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

In my case for the X64 architecture